# Finally function in php 5.3

Tags: php, try-catch-finally

Do we have "final block" (try catch final) in php 5.3?

I wrote a code in php 5.5 and I have to integrate this code in a system which only supports php 5.3

If we do not have this awesome functionality in php 5.3 then what is equivalent to this?

I have to display some messages using final block.

Any help would be appreciated. Please pardon my ignorance, this is the first time I am working in php.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is only `try` and `catch` in PHP 5.3. The `finally` block exists starting from PHP 5.5.